# Make Scheme function for 3 parameters return function for the 3d

Tags: function, return, scheme

I'm having a hard time converting this rather simple Scheme function, into a function that returns another function taking in a list and applying the former function to all elements on that list.

This function

```
(define (operList op i lis) 

    (if (= 0 (length lis)) '() 

    (cons (op i (car lis)) (operList op i (cdr lis))))

)
```

Can be called like this

```
(operList + 2 '(1 1 1))
```

and returns '(3 3 3)

However, how can I edit this function so that I can call it in the following manner

```
((operList + 2) '(1 1 1))
```

with the same results

Comment: What's wrong with thanking people for taking the time to read over my question? o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return a new function that receives the list. I took the liberty of fixing the indentation and the base case (that's not how you should ask if a list if empty!); pay special attention to the way the recursion is called now:

```
(define (operList op i)
  (lambda (lis)
    (if (null? lis)
        '()
        (cons (op i (car lis))
              ((operList op i) (cdr lis))))))
```

It works as expected:

```
((operList + 2) '(1 1 1))
=> '(3 3 3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I just started learning Scheme so I realize my code might have silly errors, and your comments are appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `map`:

```
(define operList
  (lambda (op i)
    (lambda (lst)
      (map
       (lambda (x) (op i x))
       lst))))
```